# SFTP - WinSCP: Zip a file/folder

Tags: zip, sftp, winscp

I'm transferring a file to SFTP and then trying to zip it with WinSCP. It's not working.

After my `put`  command, I'm using the following command.

```
zip -r "!?&SFTP Folder Path\MyFile.txt:?SFTP Folder Path\MyFile.zip!" !&
```

What am I doing wrong? What should I be doing? If I only want to zip a/any file with specific extension or folder, what changes do I make?

Update:

I'm getting the following log output after a file has been copied over to the sftp 
...

```
batch continue Searching for host... 
Connecting to host... 
Authenticating... 
Using username "admin". Authenticating with pre-entered password. Authenticated. Starting the session...
```

I'm using the following code after put cmd line.

```
option batch continue 
call zip -r "/sftp folder/Myfile.zip" Myfile.csv 
close 
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is a [custom command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/custom_command). The custom commands is a GUI feature of WinSCP, it has nothing to do with the scripting.

In [WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting) use the [`call` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_call).

```
call zip -r /path/MyFile.zip file1.dat file2.dat ...
```

Though make sure you are [allowed to execute shell commands on the server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/remote_command).